# What's the verb for saying "dawww"

Tags: verbs

When you see a cute animal or something and you let out a "Dawww", or something similar, what's the verb to describe it?

Comment: I do not believe there is a single-word verb, but 'sentimentally exclaim' would fit.

Comment: It’s not limited to just cute animals or the ‘aww’ sound (it can also describe a host of more high-pitched and higher-volumed reactions to a variety of exciting situations), but in many cases it would be fairly accurate to describe such an act as ***squeeing***.

Comment: Long before 'squeeing' became a thing, one might have referred to this reaction as 'melting.'

Comment: Don't have a verb. "Softening of the brain" is a phrase that comes to mind.

Answer (score 4):

The obligatory social response is to **coo** over cute animals and all babies.

> [**coo**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coo) *(verb)*
>   1.1 (of a person) speak in a soft gentle voice.
>
> - *‘Being petless, I find it hard enough when people start cooing about their cats.’*
> - *‘Hopefully, I'll then turn all mushy and gooey as I start cooing, "Aw, look at his little hands!"’*